# Orchard CMS warmup authorization exception

Tags: orchardcms

I have an Orchard site that is set to periodically generate warm up pages.

I am seeing a number of UnauthorizedAccessExceptions when the background process is trying to delete the old warmup files.

Would somebody be able to guid me as to where I can grant the relevant permissions for this in IIS? The site is hosted by a shared hosting environment to which I have access although not as admin.

```
    2013-01-15 18:44:09,078 [18] Orchard.Tasks.BackgroundService - Error while processing       background task
Orchard.OrchardCoreException: Unable to make room for file "d:\virtualservers\xxxxx\xxxxxx\wwwroot\App_Data\Sites\Default\warmup.txt.lock" in "App_Data" folder ---> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'd:\virtualservers\xxxxx\xxxxxx\wwwroot\App_Data\Sites\Default\warmup.txt.lock' is denied.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.File.InternalDelete(String path, Boolean checkHost)
   at Orchard.FileSystems.AppData.AppDataFolder.MakeDestinationFileNameAvailable(String destinationFileName) in c:\Users\sebros\My Projects\Orchard\src\Orchard\FileSystems\AppData\AppDataFolder.cs:line 79
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Orchard.FileSystems.AppData.AppDataFolder.MakeDestinationFileNameAvailable(String destinationFileName) in c:\Users\sebros\My Projects\Orchard\src\Orchard\FileSystems\AppData\AppDataFolder.cs:line 82
   at Orchard.FileSystems.LockFile.LockFile.Release() in c:\Users\sebros\My Projects\Orchard\src\Orchard\FileSystems\LockFile\L
```

Comment: What user is the app pool running under, and does it have access to delete files from that folder?

Comment: "unable to make room" seems to point to a full disk, no?

Comment: I'll have to check the user. I'm at work at the moment so will look tonight. Re. disk space - I did check that. I FTP'd a large file over to that location to prove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a permissions issue within IIS.

As the site is hosted on a shared hosting provider I had to contact them to resolve the permissions.

Hopefully useful to somebody else if they see these errors in their logs.